# Why is Windows Safe Mode Magic?

Tags: windows, heap-memory

Everyone.

I help out with I.T. for a medical practice. It turns out there’s a bug in the EMR software which shows up once in a while. (All the computers run on Windows 10 currently)

The program dies and I get the popup “*A problem has caused the program to stop working…*”

I hook up a debugger. It looks like a heap issue in their code according to the stack trace. I turn on GFlags and it hits every time.  I tell the EMR Software folks but they don’t like to claim bugs and want to prove it’s not them.

They boot the computer to Safe Mode with Networking and low and behold there’s no heap problem so they say they’re off the hook. It’s not them.

I’ve reproduced the problem on all the machines (32 and 64 bit) and in Clean Mode and logged in under the activated Administrator account but Safe Mode works every time.

I've reproduced the problem by running in a command window:

```
gflags /p /enable emrprogram.exe /full

cdb -g -x emrname.exe
```

Questions:

1. How can Safe Mode make a heap bug disappear?
2. Any suggestions for reproducing the bug in Safe Mode,  i.e. what’s really happening in Safe Mode Can I make it more like Normal Mode?

P.S. Here's the stack trace:

```
VERIFIER STOP 00000010: pid 0x238: corrupted start stamp


04F61000 : Heap handle

0014F09C : Heap block

00000000 : Block size

00000000 : Corrupted stamp




0:000> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child

0014ed20 5fa0aac9 00000010 5fa01bc8 04f61000 verifier!VerifierStopMessage+0x27e

0014ed84 5fa0ae8a 04f61000 00000004 0014f09c 
verifier!AVrfpDphReportCorruptedBlock+0x239

0014ede0 5fa0b3c2 04f61000 0014f09c 00000004 verifier!AVrfpDphCheckNormalHeapBlock+0x11a

0014ee00 5fa09cf3 04f61000 05230000 01000002 verifier!AVrfpDphNormalHeapFree+0x22

0014ee24 77d76c42 04f60000 01000002 0014f09c verifier!AVrfDebugPageHeapFree+0xe3

0014ee84 77cca934 0014f09c 014b1fe2 04f60000 ntdll!RtlDebugFreeHeap+0x3c

0014ef40 77cc9238 00000000 0014f09c 44ce6ff8 ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap+0xb4

*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for image00400000

0014ef68 01f3d902 04f60000 00000000 0014f09c ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x268

WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.

0014f0b8 01f3c6c6 0014f1dc 08f58f70 0dab2f88 image00400000+0x1b3d902

0014f21c 01f3c4b9 0dab2f88 0014f2d8 08f58f70 image00400000+0x1b3c6c6

0014f320 02053935 0dab2f88 0014f454 0014f500 image00400000+0x1b3c4b9

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVBVM60.DLL -

0014f4f4 66051d33 08f58f70 0014f510 0051c783 image00400000+0x1c53935

0014f510 66052034 0051c783 0014f57c 00000002 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x236f3

0014f528 6605211a 08f58fe8 0014f6c4 0014f57c MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x239f4

0014f6cc 77b3b3cc 00000009 0659b040 00000000 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x23ada

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files\emrname\IGThreed40.ocx -

0014f72c 2411bead 0c7e0fac 00000016 241343f8 GDI32!ScriptStringAnalyzeGlyphs+0x2cc

0014f98c 2410ae97 0c71fd60 2413794c 0c71fff0 IGThreed40!DLLGetDocumentation+0x27d1

0014f9a4 24116fda 09f4b6fc 16fa9fd4 759fb0ff IGThreed40+0xae97

0014f9c8 759dc807 0c71fff0 000001cc 00000004 IGThreed40+0x16fda

0014fc70 2411b679 0cac5638 0c71fff0 fffffdd9 OLEAUT32!CTypeInfo2::Invoke+0x517

0014fc9c 24106d11 0c71fd60 fffffdd9 0cac5638 IGThreed40!DLLGetDocumentation+0x1f9d

0014fcd0 241179f6 0c71fd60 fffffdd9 6601aea8 IGThreed40+0x6d11

0014fcfc 66049039 0c71fd60 fffffdd9 6601aea8 IGThreed40+0x179f6

0014fd44 66049a8a 0c7e0e8c 08baaf0c 0000000d MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x1a9f9

0014fd74 66083900 0c7e0e8c 000a037e 0000104d MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x1b44a

0014fd9c 66083d58 08b8ce6c 0014fe50 00000001 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x552c0

0014fdd8 6601ca5e 08b8ce6c 00c8030c 7552d390 MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x55718

0014fe08 6600a782 0014fe50 ffffffff 6600a72e MSVBVM60!Zombie_Release+0xe005

0014fe34 6600a6b0 07097f8c 0014fe50 ffffffff MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x3ab

0014fe78 6600a63f ffffffff 07097f8c 07080000 MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x2d9

0014febc 6600a51d 0709dfcc ffffffff 00000238 MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x268

0014fed8 6600a4e8 07097f88 0709dfcc ffffffff MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x146

0014fefc 66003644 ffffffff 03f40670 03f40670 MSVBVM60!_vbaStrToAnsi+0x111

0014ff78 00489fca 004a30b4 779995f4 0020d000 MSVBVM60!ThunRTMain+0xa0

0014ff94 77cb241a 0020d000 014b0f7e 00000000 image00400000+0x89fca

0014ffdc 77cb23e9 ffffffff 77d339e7 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2b

0014ffec 00000000 03f40670 0020d000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

0:000>
```

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-safe-mode#1TC=windows-7 explains what is different about Safe Mode. Note the part about a limited set of drivers (which also includes a basic video driver). This means a vastly reduced memory load, which can mean that problems related to drivers and memory issues can disappear. And no, you cannot make Safe Mode more like Normal Mode - that is counter to the entire purpose for the existence of Safe Mode. With that being said, this site is for questions related to debugging *your code*, not that of some third party executable..

Comment: Ask your wife what she does when a patient is vague about their symptoms. I think your wife can share with you many instances of getting clarification before she can do anything more. The people that can help you are diagnosticians as much as your wife is. Things like "**a** debugger", ""a heap issue" and "turn on GFlags" are vague. To reply to your question "How can Safe Mode make a heap bug disappear" directly, probably more information is necessary.

Comment: Good Point. (and nice analogy as well.) By debugger, I mean cdb.exe. By GFlags, I ran "gflags /p enable emrprogram.exe /full" By heap issue, I'll give you the stack trace in the original question above. Thanks, Mr. H